# How many grid rows contain string... Expression Engine

Tags: count, expressionengine

I am in need of a simple way to find the count of grid rows that contain a string in one of it's columns. For example, I have a 'grid' fieldtype called 'Units' and inside there are 4 columns, one of those is a checkbox field type named 'Status'. Which has the option of 'Available' or 'Sold'.

How can I easily count how many rows have 'Available' checked or 'Sold' checked?

I've tried the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="property"}
{units}
{if {units:status} == "Available"}
{units:total_rows}
{/if}
{/units}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This however, simply gives me the total count of how many rows there are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To help you understand what i'm trying to achieve. I simply want to display a "Sold Out" message if the count is 0 or an "Available" message if the count is 1 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, incase anyone is having this issue, you can query the total_rows tag as follows:

```
{units:total_rows search:status="Sold"}
```

Hope this helps anyone.